# Get user profile by email using JSOM in SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I'm working on SharePoint hosted app in SP 2013 Online using JSOM. My requirement is to get user profile properties by using email id. 
I know that we can get any user profile using input as account name e.g.

```
userProfileProperty = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName, propertyName)
```

but is it possible to do the same using email id of a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj667887(v=office.15).aspx) method expects `accountName` parameter to be provided in claim format

### About identity claim format

SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010 display identity claims with the following encoding format:

```
<IdentityClaim>:0<ClaimType><ClaimValueType><AuthMode>|<OriginalIssuer (optional)>|<ClaimValue>
```

Follow this article for an explanation.

In case of SharePoint Online (SPO) the following format is used for an account:

```
i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

The claim could be constructed from email address:

```
function toClaim(email)
{
    return String.format('i:0#.f|membership|{0}',email);
}
```

### Example

```
var email = 'username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'; 
var profilePropertyName = "PreferredName";
var accountName = toClaim(email);


function getUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName,profilePropertyName,success,failure)
{
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
   var userProfileProperty = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName,profilePropertyName);

   context.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
      success(userProfileProperty);
   }, 
   failure);
}
```

Usage

```
getUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName,profilePropertyName,
   function(property){
      console.log(property.get_value());
   }, 
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());    
   });
```

### References

[SharePoint 2013: Claims Encoding](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-2013-claims-encoding-also-valuable-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Vadim a lot for clearing my doubt. I have a query regarding the account name format. You mentioned the format of account name as i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com. Does the account name always ends with ".onmicrosoft.com"? Is it possible to change this to something like i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.com?